# Enable stack trace in Jetty logs

Tags: logging, jetty, verbosity

I'm running Artifactory, which is using Jetty a web server.

Sometimes the server is throwing a http 500 error. However there's no accurate message with it.

How do I tell Jetty to enable something like a stack trace or an error message related to this error 500, which I can use to troubleshoot this issue?

This is what I currently have:

```
15309:10.2.50.76 -  -  [29/Aug/2011:19:30:20 +0000] "GET /artifactory/libs-snapshots-local/com/mycompany/project/project-component/8.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml HTTP/1.1" 500 7087
```

I need a proper message saying where the error comes from.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide examples of the output in question?

Comment: @noamt question edited to answer your comment.

Comment: To determine whether this error originated in Artifactory or not, you can review Artifactory's request log (${ARTIFACTORY_HOME}/logs/request.log); if this request appears in that log file, then this request has in fact reached Artifactory.

Comment: Apart from that, you can lower Jetty's log level in Artifactory's logback configuration (${ARTIFACTORY_HOME}/etc/logback.xml).